# Can you combine two different fonts into a variable font axis

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts, font-family

I am interested in variable fonts, but have very limited knowledge of how they work because I am a designer and not a developer.

If I have two fonts in ideal format (otf, woff, etc) can I hook them up to become a variable web font, where one side of the axis is the first font and the other side is the other font?

Does that interpretation exist natively or is there any framework out there that can interpolate and provide an axis to shift between the two fonts?

Answer (score 1):

Two fonts can be combined into a variable font if they have a similar set of glyphs and for those glyphs that change between them, each glyphs need to have the same number of contour points.

Look at [fontmake](https://github.com/googlefonts/fontmake) and the [designspace format](https://robofont.com/documentation/how-tos/creating-designspace-files/#the-designspace-file-format) to learn more on how you can setup fontmake with designspaces to output a variable font.